Catching a Cat on an Infinite N-Dimensional Space
You have just entered a very large room in $n$-dimensional space ($n \ge 2$). They are labeled $(1, 1, 1, ..., 1)$, $(2, 1, 1, ..., 1)$ and so on,  with an infinite number of rooms in each dimension. In one of these boxes $(a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_n)$, a cat is hiding. but you do not know which one. The cat may not go to coordinates less than $1$.
Every day at noon, you may check any box to see if the cat is inside. If it is, you win and the game is done. If not, at midnight, the cat will move orthogonally to one of its neighboring boxes. For example, if $n = 3$ and the cat is at box $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$, the cat can move to any of these boxes:

$(a_1+1, a_2, a_3)$
$(a_1-1, a_2, a_3)$
$(a_1, a_2 + 1, a_3)$
$(a_1, a_2 - 1, a_3)$
$(a_1, a_2, a_3 + 1)$
$(a_1, a_2, a_3 - 1)$

After that, you enter the room at noon the next day again and the game continues
For what values of $n$ can you find a strategy to win this game every time?

Bonus riddle
Let's suppose the cat can move to any adjacent box, not only orthogonally but also diagonally.
That means, if the cat starts at $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$, it can move to boxes it cannot move to in the non-bonus riddle, such as:

$(a_1, a_2+1, a_3-1)$
$(a_1-1, a_2-1, a_3)$
$(a_1-1, a_2+1, a_3+1)$
$(a_1-1, a_2, a_3+1)$

For what values of $n$ can you still find a strategy to win this game every time?

Can the cat go to negative coordinates?

Are you allowing probabilistic strategies whose chance of winning converges to 1 but is never guaranteed? Otherwise I don't see how it is at all possible to win, since the cat can always have moved to any adjacent square that isn't the one you picked.

@xnor Yes, they are allowed.

If a randomized strategy is required, then this should probably be clarified in the question.

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

I guess you use the words "rooms" and "boxes" as synonyms.

Related: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/126943/78610


 We shall call the room $o=(1,1,\dots,1)$ the origin. Given a nonnegative integer $m$, let $R_m$ be the set of the rooms which the cat initially placed at the origin can reach in at most $m$ days and $r_m=|R_m|$. They are exactly the rooms $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i-1)\le m$ in the original game and $\max_{i=1}^n (a_i-1)\le m$ in the bonus game.


 Given a function $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that $\lim_{m\to\infty} f(m)-m=\infty$, there is the following probabilistic cat catching strategy $S_f$: at the $m$th day check a room of $R_{f(m)}$ with the probability $p_{f,m}=\frac 1{r_{f(m)}}$ each.


 Since $\lim_{m\to\infty} f(m)-m=\infty$, there exists a natural number $M$ such that the cat is in a room of $R_{f(m)}$ for any $m\ge M$. So the probability that the cat will remain free is at most $$P_{f,M}=\prod_{m=M}^\infty 1-p_{f,m}=\prod_{m=M}^\infty 1-\frac{1}{r_{f(m)}}.$$  The probability $P_{f,M}=0$ iff $P_{f,1}=0$, so we have to test the convergence of the latter product. It is well-known (see, for instance, 402 in Grigorii Fichtenholz, Differential and Integral Calculus, v. II, 7-th edition, Moscow: Nauka, 1970, in Russian) that $P_{f,1}=0$ iff the series $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{r_{f(m)}}$ diverges.


 I expect that $r_m\approx \frac{(m+1)^n}{n!}$ in the original game and $r_m=(m+1)^n$ in the bonus game. Since $\lim_{m\to\infty} f(m)-m=\infty$ and the series $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac 1{m}$diverges, but the series $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac 1{m^2}$ converges (to $\frac{\pi^2}6$), I expect we can ensure $P_{f,1}=0$ iff $n=1$. In the latter case for each natural $m$ we have $r_m=m+1$, so it suffices to put $f(m)=2m$.


 So we can try to show that for $n>1$ there is no probabilistic cat catching strategy. Thus to be continued..

